# Excel Find and Replace Formulas with different references

Tags: vba, excel

I have numerous cells on a worksheet with the following formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(O7:O9;"Fail");"Fail";"Pass")
```

I want to replace all the cells with this formula with the following formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(O7:O9;"");"Default";(IF(COUNTIF(O7:O9;"Fail");"Fail";"Pass")))
```

How can I change them all to the new formula in one swoop?
 It is a bunch of cells and please notice that **all the cells with a formula have different references.**

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a ctrl+h and replace the forumulae directly.

Comment: But not for all the cells at once since they have different refrences? Right? I want the new formula to have correct references...

Answer (score 0):

This should work

Just select all cells with "those" formulas you mentioned above, If you select any blank cells, or cells with different formulas, it will crash

You can alternatively select a few cells at a time

```
Sub changeFormulaOfSelectedCells()
Dim rng As Range
Dim rangeInFormula As String
Dim cellFormula As String

For Each rng In Selection
    cellFormula = rng.Formula
    rangeInFormula = Mid(cellFormula, 13, InStr(cellFormula, ";") - 13)
    rng.Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF(" & rangeInFormula & ";" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ");" & Chr(34) & "Default" & Chr(34) & ";(IF(COUNTIF(" & rangeInFormula & ";" & Chr(34) & "Fail" & Chr(34) & ");" & Chr(34) & "Fail" & Chr(34) & ";" & Chr(34) & "Pass" & Chr(34) & ")))"
    Next rng
End Sub
```

If you get an error, Just check if I have not missed replacing any `,` with `;`in the above code

Comment: Thanks a lot! You made my day!